# Correct Hilbert Style proof for $\vdash (A\vee B) \equiv (A \vee C)$?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Is this appropriate Hilbert Style proof for $\vdash (A\vee B) \equiv (A \vee C)$?

(1) $A\vee (B \equiv C ) \equiv A \vee B \equiv A \vee C$ (by the Axiom of Distributivity of $\vee$ over $\equiv$)

QED?

Comment: This is very confusing ... wwhere does $A \lor (B \equiv C)$ come from?  Also, $(A \lor B) \equiv (A \lor C)$ is not a tautology, so it should not be provable. Finally, are you using $\equiv$ both as a logical operator as well as a met-logical symbol of logical equivalence?!

Comment: They are using it as a biconditional operator (logic), taking advantage of the associative property to write $(X\equiv Y)\equiv Z$ as just $X\equiv Y\equiv Z$.  @Bram28

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks for the clarification about $\equiv$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\getsto{\leftrightarrow} (A\vee(B\getsto C))\getsto((A\vee B)\getsto(A\vee C))$ is a provable tautology in classical logic.

However, $A\vee(B\getsto C)$ is not, so you cannot use the above to prove $(A\vee B)\getsto(A\vee C)$ except conditionally.$$A\vee(B\getsto C)\vdash (A\vee B)\getsto(A\vee C)$$

Do you have a way to justify a premise of $A\vee(B\getsto C)$?

---

$(A\vee(B\equiv C))\equiv(A\vee B)\equiv(A\vee C)$ is a tautology, and well, *may* be used as an axiom for a Hilbert-esque proof system.

However, $A\vee(B\equiv C)$ is not, so you cannot use the above to prove $(A\vee B)\equiv(A\vee C)$ except conditionally. $$A\vee(B\equiv C)\vdash (A\vee B)\equiv(A\vee C)$$